# Anyone know what happened to xml-rpc.net?

Tags: c#, xml-rpc, xml-rpc.net

it seems [xml-rpc.net](http://xml-rpc.net) is no longer available? (Archive.org wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190129151012/http://xml-rpc.net/ )

Anyone have a suggestion on an xml-rpc server for c# on Windows and mono?

I tired visiting it for several days and it is gone.

Comment: the downvote isn't exactly fair. This is a popular library that seems to have little in the way of versatile replacement options except rolling their own

Comment: I think this question is out of date. The xml-rpc.net site is available. I suspect it was just offline for a while.

Comment: @MartinBrown Currently offline. I found this snapshot on github.io https://papercutsoftware.github.io/XML-RPC.NET/ or it is also available on the Internet Archive Wayback Machine https://web.archive.org/web/20210929142909/http://www.xml-rpc.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is no more available but the source code looks still available on github
[xmlrpcnet on github](https://github.com/marcosbozzani/xmlrpcnet)

It provides also the nuget packages fro client and server

Comment: This is great. Thank you.